# Sorting Divs With JQuery Based On "data-" Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to sort divs using jquery based on it's **data-enter** attribute.
Here's my JQuery for it:

```
            let result = $("#tableEls .dataDiv").sort(function (a, b) {
                console.log(+$(a).data("enter") + " < " + +$(b).data("enter"));
                return +$(a).data("enter") < +$(b).data("enter");
            }).appendTo("#tableEls");

            console.log(result);
```

However, when this is called, it doesn't reorder the divs. Here are the divs:

[image: Divs that I'm trying to sort.]

Also, here's the console output:

[image: Console Output]

I've tried many different solutions on StackOverflow but can't find any that work for me. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I can't see anything wrong.

Also, here's the screenshot of the HTML page itself with each of the four divs outlined with a black border:

[image: HTML Page]

When the **Sort Rows** button is clicked, the **enter** cell from each table and adds it as the **data-enter** attribute for each div before running the JQuery from above. So in this example, the first and second div's positions should be swapped.

Comment: The `sort` function should return 0 if the values are equal, a value greater than 0 if the first argument is greater than the second, and a value less than 0 if the first argument is less than the second. The sort function provided returns a Boolean. Typically, if the arguments are numbers, returning the equivalent of `a - b` is enough to sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sort function have to return N or -N or 0 not a boolean:

```
let result = $("#tableEls .dataDiv").sort(function (a, b) {
            console.log(+$(a).data("enter") + " - " + +$(b).data("enter"));
            return +$(a).data("enter") - +$(b).data("enter");
        }).appendTo("#tableEls");

        console.log(result);
```